# Timeout to connect in Oracle Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, npm, node-oracledb

this is my first time asking in StackOverflow

My problem is:

I'm trying to connect in some Oracle database using NodeJS (node-oracledb), and i'm getting Timeout Error or TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Help please!!.

My code:

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb')

async function test(){
    let con;

    let connetionString = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_ip)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=url_service)))'
    oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: 'C:\\oracle\\instantclient_19_16'});

    con = await oracledb.getConnection({user: "user", password: "password", connectionString: connetionString}, function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            console.log(connection)
        }
    })

}
```

When i try to connect using host_ip:port give me timenou error, but when i try using the connectionString or the url_service, give me TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Help please!!

Comment: Make sure connectivity is in place: Windows: C:\>telnet host_ip port, MacOS: nc -vz host_ip port

Comment: I don't have telnet in C:

Comment: A comment on the code: Review the [node-oracledb examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) and fix your code.  You are mixing callbacks with async/await syntax.  I suggest you remove the callbacks.

Comment: To resolve your connection problem start by using the '[Easy Connect](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#easyconnect)' syntax which is 'host:port/servicename'.   Check the port is open on the computer and that the firewall is not blocking it.  (The default port for Oracle is 1521).  You used the word 'url_service' which is suspicious - the service name and connection string are not really URLs.  Can you update your question with some (fake) values that closer to what you are using?